# Generating maven dependencies using list of jar file names

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I am on the process of converting java projects with many dependencies to maven projects.

These Java projects have dependencies, which are present in maven central. Now, I am trying to automate this conversion to the maven project to include all the libraries as dependencies and generate a maven pom.xml.

I thought of the below approach

Step 1 - Locate the version from the jar file name, if not found - search in the manifest file.

Step 2 - Locate the artifact id from the jar file name - though may not be valid for all jars.

Step 3 - For locating the group id - expand the jar file, and try to create group id using package name.

Step 4 - Verify the dependency formation using [search api](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api)

Is there a better way to perform the above steps.

Comment: 1, 2 & 4 are valid. Don't attempt 3, package name rarely matches group ID and jars can have many packages

Comment: Package name is just a option to try, as i don see any other way to find group id...

Comment: Perhaps you could use the artifact ID to get a handful of matches on Maven Central. You could then compare the group IDs on Maven Central to the packages in the jar and look for similarities

Answer (score 1):

An important additional option is to compute the SHA1 of your jar and search for it in MavenCentral.

Furthermore, you can look for a `pom.properties` file in the jar, which is present if the jar was originally built with Maven.